# Stack Exchange Moderator Candidate Statistics not loading at all

Tags: support, moderator-election

I'm trying to open the link below but it's not loading at all.

http://elections.stackexchange.com/#stackoverflow

I've been waiting quite a long time, but I'm not receiving a response at all.

[image]

Comment: `http://elections.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/election` isn't loading, that could be the cause.

Comment: @Stijn It's keep loading

Comment: I checked that link 2 days before and it loaded. So I guess the 2015 election is causing the problem...

Comment: Huh? Why does the image of the sandclock/Hourglass in that page appear as a box(like ) to me?

Comment: @Stijn Got this error for your link. Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data. Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: Waiting until SO users actually start voting for the candidates would be advisable.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Usually I'd have some sort of synopsis of what the issue was but to be honest…I just turned it off and back on again. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), for now.

I'll see if I can figure out what the cause was.

There's an additional issue where the large number of candidates in this election can [cause an API throttle violation](https://twitter.com/tmslft/status/585283363705073665) due to an apparent mishandling in the code that's supposed to account for that, so if the load finishes but some of the data is missing (i.e. the recent user activity), that's the cause. I'll try to fix that as well.

Comment: While in there, what are the chances of the badge list being expanded to cover all 20 that are used in the candidate score?

Comment: Definitely something I can take a look at. I didn't know about that until after the election started, otherwise I would have tried to get it in there before.

Comment: @TimStone Put down the bacon jerky and fix it!!

Comment: Could SE just relax the API throttling for the specific app for a small period?

Comment: @JonClements That I don't know, but I will try to get in a fix ASAP either way.

Comment: @bluefeet I'm all out, it is a sad day. SO SAD. :(

Comment: @TimStone good luck... I'd offer to help if it were in my skill-set but alas...

Comment: @TimStone It seems to be working now.